# Meteor: How do I commit edit packages from my packages folder?

Tags: git, meteor

I needed to customize a few meteor plugins from atmosphere. So I cloned them into my packages folder and edited the code. Everything in my app is working correctly but it seems like I cannot commit the edited packages.

I have tried `git add --all` to add all files but the ones in the packages folder still remain untracked.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   packages/Stripe-Easy-for-Meteor (modified content, untracked content)
    modified:   packages/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

That is what I get when I type `git status`

How can I commit these edited packages?

Comment: Is it because each of these packages has its own git repo? Should I delete .git hidden folder from the packages and then try to commit to my own repo?

Answer (score 2):

The packages folder was not being recognized by git at all. I tried running the command 'git add /packages' and it reported that the packages folder is outside the repository, even though the folder was inside the root project.

So I run the command

`git --work-tree=/ add /packages`

And it added the packages folder to the project. Now I could just run `git add --all` and then `git push` and now my packages folder is part of my project!

Answer (score 1):

if that's the route you wanna take, you'd have to make them git submodules. at the end of the day, I'd just as soon remove their .git folders & make them part of your app. if you needed to separate them (to create a shareable package), you can copy them to a new folder & then push to github. not elegant, but better than submodules.

Comment: +1 Submodules is the way to go. See also https://github.com/mizzao/CrisisMapping for another way I have set up an app with a lot of development packages.

Comment: @AndrewMao you set that up manually in the console or did you find some nifty GUI to help with submodules?

Comment: I removed the .git folder from both the packages in my packages folder that I edited from atmosphere. Now when I type git status, git does not even see the packages folder. Does not notice is as untracked content. I would like my packages folder to be committed as part of my project. How can I do this?

Comment: depending on your git manager, the packages folder may be ignored by default. In webstorm, this shows up as a red file name &  you can add it by alt+cmd+a. Check your .gitignore. If it's still screwed up, just delete the folder, clone your app repo, and re-add the packages folder without the .git folders.

Comment: @MattK My .gitignore does not specify anything that relates to the packages folder. I checked my bitbucket account and it shows the packages folder but it is still recognizing the packages inside as git submodules or something. It shows up in bitbucket as `meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 → c363632f353 [c4274734746]` I wish I could just get git to recognize the packages folder again. I created a new project and added the packages folder and it is recognized. If .gitignore is not hiding the packages folder what else could be?

Comment: I'm no git expert, but i'd try to delete the packages folder, push the changes, then pull the new commit, add the packages, and recommit & push. Unfortunately when it comes to git my solutions are almost never elegant.

Comment: Thanks I found out a way to add the packages folder. I will add the answer. Thanks for the help though.